# Electric intensity

Tags: electrostatics

Is it possible that electric intensity can be zero at a point between two unlike charges?

I have seen that electric intensity between unlike charges is zero at a point outside according to the electric lines of force figure?
So how can I solve this?

Comment: By electric intensity do you mean the electric field strength?

Comment: It is the force which is applied by an electric field on unit amount charge.

Comment: Does the hole system consist of only two charges or are we allowed to have more than two charges in the system? E.g. we put four charges on the corners of a cube ...

Comment: You should give more info, What have you tried? What do you know? The better the question, the better are (most likely) the answers... A hint, which may help: suppose you have (point-like) charge at $q_1$ at $x=-\frac d2$ and $q2$ at $x=+\frac d2$. Compute the force on a unit charge due to that. In general you'll need to add up vectors, but over a line it is easier. And there are other ways, both quantitative (e.g. computing the potential) or qualitative (what happens if you place a unit charge in between two charges, one positive, one negative? Can you draw the forces?)